# Logicify Location picker using dynamic change for input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [Logicify Location Picker](https://github.com/Logicify/jquery-locationpicker-plugin).

I want to load the map based on the lat and lng value as demonstrated in this example:

```js
<div id="us2" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>               
Lat.: <input type="text" id="us2-lat"/>
Long.: <input type="text" id="us2-lon"/>
<script>$('#us2').locationpicker({
    location: {latitude: 46.15242437752303, longitude: 2.7470703125},   
    radius: 300,
    inputBinding: {
        latitudeInput: $('#us2-lat'),
        longitudeInput: $('#us2-lon'),
    }
    });
</script>
```

But in my case i want to keep these fields for lat and long hidden and trigger change dynamically when i get the value of lat and lng based on the city name through this function:

```js
$("#city").change(function() {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': "" + $("#city").val() + ", Pakistan"
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      $("#lat").val(results[0].geometry.location.lat()).trigger('change');
      $("#lng").val(results[0].geometry.location.lng()).trigger('change');
      alert($("#lat").val() + " " + $("#lng").val());
    } else {
      alert("Something got wrong " + status);
    }
  });
});
```

here are my hidden fields:

```
<input type="hidden" id="lat">
<input type="hidden" id="lng">
```

plus i have a select with id = "city" having some city names i.e lahore

and here is what i'm doing:

```js
            var inital_lat = "31.554397"; /*lahore pakistan*/
            var inital_lng = "74.356078";
            $('#locationpicker').locationpicker({
              location: {
                latitude: inital_lat,
                longitude: inital_lng
              },
              radius: 100,
              inputBinding: {
                latitudeInput: $("#lat"),
                longitudeInput: $("#lng")
              }
            });
            $("#city").change(function() {
              var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
              geocoder.geocode({
                'address': "" + $("#city").val() + ", Pakistan"
              }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  $("#lat").val(results[0].geometry.location.lat()).trigger('change'); /* i've also tried .change() */
                  $("#lng").val(results[0].geometry.location.lng()).trigger('change');

                  alert($("#lat").val() + " " + $("#lng").val());
                } else {
                  alert("Something got wrong " + status);
                }
              });
            });
```

if i make textfields type = text and enter some value and press enter the map dynamically changes, but for dynamic change (keeping fields hidden) it does not  work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

here is a code from locationpicker.jquery.js file:

```js
 if (inputBinding.latitudeInput) {
   inputBinding.latitudeInput.on("change", function(e) {
     if (!e.originalEvent) {
       return
     }
     GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, new google.maps.LatLng($(this).val(), gmapContext.location.lng()), function(context) {
       context.settings.onchanged.apply(gmapContext.domContainer, [GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(context.location), context.radius, false]);
     });
   });
 }
 if (inputBinding.longitudeInput) {
   inputBinding.longitudeInput.on("change", function(e) {
     if (!e.originalEvent) {
       return
     }
     GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, new google.maps.LatLng(gmapContext.location.lat(), $(this).val()), function(context) {
       context.settings.onchanged.apply(gmapContext.domContainer, [GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(context.location), context.radius, false]);
     });
   });
 }
```

Looks like it looks for the change in lat and lng field, and thats what i'm doing changing it dynamically. whats the matter?

Comment: Triggering a `change` event will cause something to fire that is watching for that event. In the code you presented here, I do not see anything watching (read: listening to) the change event on the hidden `#lat` and `#lon` fields. In other words, there is no `$("#lat").on("change", function() { /* change code */ });`

Comment: the inputBinding automatically reads the change when i type any thing manually.

Comment: Yes, you said that in the question, but you don't show any code for it.

Comment: change event on input is only triggered when textfield loses focus, right?

Comment: its in the js file of the logicify. i also havnt read that, i just read it in example that it reads for change. Debugging js is a mess u know

Comment: if i type any lan value then focus on other input and type lng value remove focus from that too the map changes, i want this behavior dynamically with fields hidden

Comment: Lines 221 and 230 contain the binding code for the lat and lon fields. You can try adding some alerts there to test your code.

Comment: inside inputBinding?

Comment: i just don't understand, every thing works fine when i lose focus from the input after typing in the lan and lat values. Wht not dynamically? here is what i have also tried: $("#lat").val(results[0].geometry.location.lat()).trigger('change').focus().val($("#lat").val()+" ").blur();
                        $("#lng").val(results[0].geometry.location.lng()).trigger('change').focus().val($("#lng").val()+" ").blur();

Comment: I meant in the Logicify js file, inside the on change function, before and after that if statement. I'm wondering if that change is getting fired off.

Comment: I've posted that code in the update

Comment: Right, but edit the code and add an alert or a console.log before each if in the on change function to see if the function is getting fired off. There's two options, it's not firing, or it is firing but not updating the map. You need to find out which

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, for a quick solution you can change the code of the library locationpicker.jquery.js from the code you have pasted to this:

```
if (inputBinding.latitudeInput) {
   inputBinding.latitudeInput.on("change", function(e) {
     if (!e.originalEvent) {
       //return
     }
     GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, new google.maps.LatLng($(this).val(), gmapContext.location.lng()), function(context) {
       context.settings.onchanged.apply(gmapContext.domContainer, [GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(context.location), context.radius, false]);
     });
   });
 }
 if (inputBinding.longitudeInput) {
   inputBinding.longitudeInput.on("change", function(e) {
     if (!e.originalEvent) {
       //return
     }
     GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, new google.maps.LatLng(gmapContext.location.lat(), $(this).val()), function(context) {
       context.settings.onchanged.apply(gmapContext.domContainer, [GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(context.location), context.radius, false]);
     });
   });
 }
```

Just comment twice the return in `if (!e.originalEvent) {`

This is NOT the best solution, because you are changing the library, and if you update the library you lose your changes.

Answer (score 1):

The way you trigger the textboxes won't work.
Trigger using an event object. Refactor your `$("#city").change()` event like this

```
            $("#city").change(function (evt) {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': "" + $("#city").val() + ", Pakistan"
            }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    evt.type = 'change';//change the event's type to change whatever it was originally
                    $("#lat").val(results[0].geometry.location.lat()).trigger(evt); //use the modified event object to trigger rather passing event's name
                    $("#lng").val(results[0].geometry.location.lng()).trigger(evt);

                    alert($("#lat").val() + " " + $("#lng").val());
                } else {
                    alert("Something got wrong " + status);
                }
            });
        });
```

Hope this helps.